# Generating a dictionary of namedtuples from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Currently, am working with Python 3.6 and Pandas to optimise a process. The process is using Pandas. The final step of the process is to generate a dictionary of `namedtuples`. I am trying to use the `apply` process to efficiently convert the pandas `groupby` into a list of `namedtuples`.

```
from collections import namedtuple                                          
import pandas as pd
dfdata= [('cat01','t1', 50), ('cat01','t2',60) ,('cat01','t3',70),('cat02','t1', 60), ('cat02','t2', 80)]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=dfdata, columns=['cat','term','value'])
 df.groupby('cat')['term','value'].apply(lambda x: x.term.tolist()).to_dict()
{'cat01': ['t1', 't2', 't3'], 'cat02': ['t1', 't2']}
```

I am failing to generate the data as a list of `namedtuples` as below. Any pointers on how I can tackle it?

```
 mydata= namedtuple('entry', 'term val', verbose=False)
 <some code>
 {'cat01': [entry(term='t1', val=50), entry(term='t2', val=60), entry(term='t3', val=70)], 'cat02': [entry(term='t1', val=60), entry(term='t2', val=80)]}
```

Thanks
Kenneth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Using a list comprehension. First, define a function.

```
def f(x):
    return [mydata(i, j) for i, j in zip(x.term, x.value)]
```

Now, call `f` inside `groupby.apply`, and convert the result to a dictionary using `to_dict`.

```
df.groupby('cat').apply(f).to_dict() 
{
    'cat01': [
         entry(term='t1', val=50),
         entry(term='t2', val=60),
         entry(term='t3', val=70)
     ],
    'cat02': [
         entry(term='t1', val=60), 
         entry(term='t2', val=80)
     ]
}
```

Performance wise, this is pretty decent, even for large data.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.groupby('cat').apply(f).to_dict() 
1 loop, best of 3: 575 ms per loop
```

You *can*, however, improve performance, by `zip`ping the values and not the series (like this; `zip(x['term'].tolist(), x['value'].tolist())`) at which point, it comes down to `532 ms per loop`.

---

**Option 2**
Here's a creative use of `np.vectorize`. First, create a "vectorised" version of `mydata` -

```
v = np.vectorize(mydata, otypes=[mydata])
df.groupby('cat').apply(lambda x: v(x.term, x.value).tolist()).to_dict()
```

Which returns the same result. Using the same setup as above,

```
%timeit df.groupby('cat').apply(lambda x: v(x.term, x.value).tolist()).to_dict()    
1 loop, best of 3: 498 ms per loop
```

`vectorize` appears to be marginally faster than the loopy solution outlined above. Bear in mind, however, that timings vastly differ based on the structure and size of data, so I'd encourage you to run your own tests before drawing any conclusions.